# SvelteKit how to handle authenticated WebSocket connections

Tags: django, websocket, socket.io, svelte, sveltekit

I have a Django backend that accepts WebSocket connections under a given url. The url takes a JWT token as parameter to authenticate users trying to use a certain websocket.

I'm trying to connect to a WebSocket from my SvelteKit frontend. The problem I'm having is that I can only access the Http-Only cookies containing my access & refresh key from within my `+page.server.ts` endpoint files. How would I go about authenticating the connection while also establishing a connection from the client side to access messages being sent via the WebSocket?

Currently I've been following [this](https://youtu.be/mAcKzdW5fR8) tutorial using a custom vite plugin as well as socket.io but it doesn't seem to be trying to achieve what I'm trying to work towards.

Any help, code samples and ideas on how to handle this problem would be very appreciated!